# Android MyAdapter can't be static

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am having some trouble with this piece of code:

MyAdapter.java:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;


public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: return new SpeedZonesFragment();
        case 1: return new DistanceFragment();
        case 2: return new FuelConsumptionFragment();
        default: return null;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private MyAdapter myAdapter;
    private ViewPager myViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.view_pager);

        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        myViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

view_pager.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view_pager" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My problem goes that every example i can find declares MyAdapter as a `public static class` however `Eclipse` raise the error: `Illegal modifier for the class MyAdapter; only public, abstract & final are permitted`.

If i try to run my code without the static it returns (from LogCat):

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException`
`02-02 23:13:26.076: E/AndroidRuntime(928):`
`at simcas.fartberegneren.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)`

**EDIT:** Line 23 is the line `myViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);`

Clearly i am doing something wrong but i just can't locate it.

Comment: Care to show `view_pager.xml`? And no, it shouldn't be `static`.

Comment: @Eric: view_pager is edited in - sorry for missing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, no, `static` classes are only used for inner classes wherein the inner class's instances should not be tied to the outer class's instance. (That is, in an outer class, the `static` modified should not be used.)

Second, the null pointer is in the statement `myViewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);`, as you deduced, meaning `myViewPager` is null. Therefore, the `findViewById()` is returning null (item not found):

```
myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Notice, in your XML: `android:id="@+id/view_pager"`. The above line should then be:

```
myViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

Comment: Oh lord, I am imbarrassed by my typo! Thank you :-)

Comment: And thanks for pointing out with the `static` - now i understand it!